# Expresion regular para extraer el ASIN de Amazon de una URL

Tags: php, regex

Estoy intentando extraer el contenido del código ASIN en PHP. Y no tengo ni idea qué estoy haciendo mal para que no devuelva el string que deseo extraer.

en este caso, deseo extraer el contenido únicamente del codigo ASIN (`B01ETRGE7M`) de:

```
$url = "/Fire-TV-Stick-Basic-Edition/dp/B01ETRGE7M/ref=zg_bs_electronics_1/257-1105669-2334965?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GC2WM7K4BAH0E68ZWRKS";

function asaber($valor){
    return preg_match("/^\/[dp]{2}\/\w{10}$/", $valor);
}

echo asaber($url);
```

El código ASIN:

1. No siempre es el 3er dato en la URL, puede variar de posición igual que puede variar en la letra que empieza, ya que también puede entrar números.
2. Siempre contendrá números y letras, en Mayúsculas y minúsculas.
3. La URL es de Amazon.

Comment: ¿El código `ASIN` siempre es el 3er dato en la `URL`? ¿El formato siempre será letras mayúsculas y números? ¿Es la `URL` a un link de `Amazon`?

Comment: 1) No siempre es el 3er dato en la URL, puede variar de posición igual que puede variar en la letra que empieza, ya que también puede entrar numeros.

2) Siempre contendrá Numeros y Letras, en Mayúsculas y minúsculas

3) La URL si que es de Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que leí en:

1. [Determine if 10 digit string is valid Amazon ASIN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2123131/5290909)
2. [Get ASIN from pasted Amazon url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21700573/5290909)
3. [How write a regex that matches only when there's a slash OR nothing after the match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21049068/5290909)

no hay una sintaxis concreta para poder diferenciarlo, excepto que:

- Empieza por `B` y tiene exactamente 9 caracteres más en mayúsculas, o es un ISBN.
- Tienen que estar inmediatamente seguidas por `/`, `?`, `#`, o el final del texto.
- *Suele* estar precedido por

  - `/o/`, `/ASIN/` o `/e/`; o
  - `/dp/` o `/gp/product/`, opcionalmente con una carpeta en el medio antes del ASIN.

Estas son reglas inferidas a partir de la prueba y error, por lo que en el futuro podría no coincidir con algún código. Además, no son reglas muy estrictas, por lo que se pueden esperar falsos positivos.

Para coincidir con una `B` seguida de 9 alfanuméricos en mayúsculas, o un ISBN:

```
~/\K(?:B[\dA-Z]{9}|\d{9}[\dX])(?=$|[/?#])~
```

Y si exigimos que esté precedido por las carpetas que suelen presentarse:

```
~/(?:[eo]|ASIN|(?:gp|dp/product)(?:/[^/]+)??)/\K(?:B[\dA-Z]{9}|\d{9}[\dX])(?=$|[/?#])~
```

Código:

```
function extraerASIN($url){
    $regex = '~/(?:[eo]|ASIN|(?:gp|dp/product)(?:/[^/]+)??)/\K(?:B[\dA-Z]{9}|\d{9}[\dX])(?=$|[/?#])~';
    if (preg_match( $regex, $url, $match)) {
        return $match[0];
    } else {
        return false; //No se encontró
    }
}
```

En todo caso, esta función podría dar resultados falsos. Lo recomendado es utilizar la API de Amazon.

Comment: Dices Mariano que es mejor utilizar la API de AMAZON. Tengo una pregunta haber si me puedes solventar. Desde la API de Amazon puedes extraer el contenido de los nuevos productos que están en oferta.???
P.D. Me refiero si puedes extraer datos de goldbox

Comment: @Fumatamax no tengo idea, nunca la usé. Me imagino que sí, o al menos poder obtener el ASIN de un producto para luego extraer la info que estás buscando, pero no conozco la estructura de las APIs de Amazon.